# Alfresco - Methods to get Attachement

Tags: java, rest, alfresco, activiti

I have tried this
    `@Override
    public void notify(DelegateExecution arg0) throws Exception{`

followed by

```
taskService = arg0.getEngineServices().getTaskService();
String id = arg0.getProcessInstanceId();
List <Attachment> attach = taskService.getProcessInstanceAttachments(id);
```

However I didn't get any attachment. As **attach.size()** was **0**.
Need help regarding this.

Or should I try alfresco RESTful api to get attachment

Answer (score 2):

Kangkan,

Are you using Community Edition or Enterprise Edition of Activiti?
I ask because the Enterprise Edition (and V6 Community Edition) use a different mechanism to store attachments and so you may get the behavior you are seeing.

If using Enterprise Edition, then you will need to use platform contentService rather than the taskService to retrieve attachments.

you would use contentService.getAllContentForTask(taskId)

Hope this helps,
Greg

Comment: Mine is enterprise edition. However I didn't follow you. `ApplicationContext ctx = ApplicationContextHelper.getApplicationContext(); 
  ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = (ServiceRegistry) ctx.getBean(ServiceRegistry.SERVICE_REGISTRY); 
  ContentService contentService = serviceRegistry.getContentService();`    Now how to get Attachment from here. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code for same.

```
ActivitiScriptNode scriptNode = (ActivitiScriptNode) arg0
                            .getVariable(WorkflowNotificationUtils.PROP_PACKAGE);
                    NodeRef workflowPackage = scriptNode.getNodeRef();

                    List<ChildAssociationRef> childAssociationRefList = nodeService.getChildAssocs(workflowPackage);
                    for (ChildAssociationRef child : childAssociationRefList) {
                        System.out.println(child.getChildRef());
                    }
```

Where *child.getChildRef()* represents node reference of the document.